Error Using AWS Built-in Fluent Bit to Send Logs to Elastic Cloud from EKS Fargate
I am using EKS Fargate and trying to use AWS built-in Fluent Bit to send logs to Elastic Cloud, but I am encountering the following error:
{ "log": "[2024/05/16 14:35:17] [error] [output:es:es.0] HTTP status=400 URI=/_bulk, response:" }
{
    "log": "{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"x_content_parse_exception\",\"reason\":\"[1:24] Unexpected character ('l' (code 108)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\\n at [Source: (byte[])\\\"{\\\"create\\\":{\\\"_index\\\":\\\"\\\"leoh-logging\\\"\\\"}}\\\"; line: 1, column: 24]\"}],\"type\":\"x_content_parse_exception\",\"reason\":\"[1:24] Unexpected character ('l' (code 108)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\\n at [Source: (byte[])\\\"{\\\"create\\\":{\\\"_index\\\":\\\"\\\"leoh-logging\\\"\\\"}}\\\"; line: 1, column: 24]\",\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"json_parse_exception\",\"reason\":\"Unexpected character ('l' (code 108)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\\n at [Source: (byte[])\\\"{\\\"create\\\":{\\\"_index\\\":\\\"\\\"leoh-logging\\\"\\\"}}\\\"; line: 1, column: 24]\"}},\"status\":400}"
}

Here is my output configuration:
  [OUTPUT]
  Name  es
  Match *
  Index "leoh-logging"
  Host  xxx
  Port  9243
  HTTP_User elastic-beats
  HTTP_Passwd xxxx
  tls   On
  tls.verify Off
  Suppress_Type_Name On

I have checked my configuration and ensured that the credentials are correct. However, I still receive this error. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or has experience in resolving this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much!

The error likely originate from your [Filter] section. Paste the fully config for further checkout.

I only use the output, not the filter. This is a built-in feature of Fluent Bit from AWS EKS Fargate. is there a way to show its default filter? @gohm'c
